# NW.js + vue-cli: how to read a local file?

Tags: webpack, node-webkit, vue-cli

I am building a `vue-cli` based `nw.js` application. I'm pointing `nw.js` to localhost (via `"main"` in the `package.json`) during development, so that I have instant updates when editing the app code. I'm using `concurrently` in my `npm` scripts to `"npm run serve"` and run the `nw.js` exec at the same time. So far so good.

I find myself in the need of reading a text file (that somehow should end up alongside the ones that webpack outputs when I'll build the production app; perhaps I can just put it in the `public` folder). At the moment it sits in `/src/photoshop/main.jsx`, but I seem to be unable to properly reference it when running the development server.

I am currently trying to:

```js
const fs = nw.require("fs"),
  path = nw.require("path"),
  filePath = path.join(__dirname, "photoshop", "main.jsx");
fs.readFileSync(filePath, (err, data) => { /* stuff */})
```

No luck, all path permutations lead to nothing. As a background, I have to read the file and then send its content (as a string – it is a Photoshop scripting library) to an Adobe Photoshop Generator plugin for evaluation via Socket.io. Everything else is set up, I just need to find a way to point `readFileSynch` to the proper location.

Perhaps, I should instruct webpack (see [here](https://cli.vuejs.org/guide/webpack.html#adding-a-new-loader)) to add a new loader for the `jsx` file, so that it gets preserved/copied to the final bundle. But again, how can I point to it both during development and in the production build? Thanks.